# UWP OneDrive storage space

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, onedrive

I have a c# UWP App, that makes use of the [OneDrive API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK) to store files in the `approot` (special folder for my App only). I know, that I can get the total space of OneDrive [this way](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/drive.htm), but it doesn't tell me, how much space my App takes.

Is there a fast way to tell, how much space my App takes to store these files there (instead of iterating through all items)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brad said, `approot` like any other OneDrive item has a metadata. And in item's [metadata](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm) has a `size` property which represents size of the item in bytes. So we can use this property to get the total space your app takes.

As [App Folder](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/appfolder.htm) described, we can use `GET /drive/special/approot` to get your app folder's metadata and when using [OneDrive .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK), the code will like:

```
var item = await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Name}'s size is {item.Size}");
```

However as I tested, when we use this code in UWP, we will encounter a cache issue. Even your app folder's size has changed, this API will return the same value as the first time you run it.

This is because while [Get metadata for a OneDrive item](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/get.htm), it has an optional request headers `if-none-match` and if this request header is included and the eTag (or cTag) provided matches the current tag on the file, an `HTTP 304 Not Modified` response is returned.

And in UWP, using `HttpClient` will automatically add this header in request, if the `eTag` is not changed, `HttpClient` will not get the newest info, it will return the data it cached. According to [Item resource type](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm):

> **Note:** The `eTag` and `cTag` properties work differently on containers (folders). The `cTag` value is modified when content or metadata of any descendant of the folder is changed. The `eTag` value is only modified when the folder's properties are changed, except for properties that are derived from descendants (like `childCount` or `lastModifiedDateTime`).

So in most case, app folder's `eTag` won't change and when we use [OneDrive .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK) or default `HttpClient` in UWP to get app folder's metadata, we will get the cached data. To see this clearly, we can use [fiddler](/questions/tagged/fiddler) to trace the network, and we will find in the request headers, `If-None-Match` is added and the real response from OneDrive is `HTTP 304 Not Modified`.
[image]

To solve this issue, we can use [`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class with [`HttpBaseProtocolFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.aspx) class and [`HttpCacheControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.filters.httpcachecontrol.aspx) class to disable the cache like following:

```
var oneDriveClient = await OneDriveClientExtensions.GetAuthenticatedUniversalClient(new[] { "wl.signin", "onedrive.readwrite" });

var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/approot"));
request.Headers.Authorization = new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("Bearer", oneDriveClient.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken);

var response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request);

var item = oneDriveClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<Item>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Name}'s size is {item.Size}");
```

**PS:** To make this method work, we need make sure there is no local HTTP cache. So we'd better uninstall the app first and do not use `await oneDriveClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.Request().GetAsync()` in the app.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch your app's folder (via `approot`) the value of the `size` property returned on the item should be a reflection of the amount of space your application is using (since for a folder the value is the sum of the size of all files stored within it, at any level).